# How to parse XML in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I'm getting xml in SQL Server, and I need to get `businessDate` value

I tried this

```
Select C.value('(businessDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS 
FROM @input.nodes('/MealsUsed/*') AS T(C)
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MealsUsed businessDate="10/09/2013" count="10" institutionID="Test">
<MealUsed>
    <TransactionDate>02/05/2013 08:10:06</TransactionDate>
    <LocationID>8</LocationID>
    <Swipes>1</Swipes>
</MealUsed>
<MealUsed>
```

Comment: And what happened when you did that?

Comment: Also, can we assume that you actually have a name between the `AS` and the `FROM`?  Or is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`businessDate` is attribute, not element, so you have to use it with `@`:

```
select
    C.value('@businessDate', 'datetime') as businessDate
from @input.nodes('MealsUsed') as T(C)
```

Actually, since `businessDate` is not in xml-date format, i'd be better to get it to varchar and then convert with [appropriate format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
select
    convert(datetime, C.value('@businessDate', 'varchar(10)'), 103) as businessDate
from @input.nodes('MealsUsed') as T(C)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25176)</kbd>**